# Closed form expression of $\Gamma(\frac{5}{3})$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, factorial, gamma-function

So I made up this integral here: $$\int_0^\infty x^4e^{-x^3}dx$$And by substitution we get $$\int_0^\infty x^4e^{-x^3}dx=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^\infty u^{\frac{2}{3}}e^{-u}du=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{5}{3})}{3}$$Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the analytic continuation of $(x-1)!$. So is there any exact form for $\Gamma(\frac{5}{3})$? I tried using Euler's reflection formula and the Legendre multiplication formula but it led me no where.

Comment: Use Legendre's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula with $z=2$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#General_rational_argument

Comment: @pathfinder This doesn't work.

Comment: The only rational numbers $\alpha$ where $\Gamma(\alpha)$ has a known closed form (in terms of things more simple that gamma function) are the integers and half-integers.

Comment: After converting to $\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)=2^\frac23\sqrt[3]{\pi \omega_2}$, use the [omega 2 constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=w_2) for another closed form

Comment: I guess $\omega_2$ is even less known that $\Gamma(\frac13)$.

Comment: @Kamal Saleh ahh, sorry I miss-viewed the 3 as a 2 on my mobile phone when I looked yesterday. My bad. I need some better glasses 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that an elementary closed form is possible (since $\Gamma(1/3)$ does not have an elementary expression), but here's I think the best you can do. Start by using [Gauss' multiplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula):
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\Gamma\left(z+\frac{i}{k}\right)=(2\pi)^{\frac{k-1}{2}}k^{\frac{1-2kz}{2}}\Gamma(kz)$$
with $z=1$ and $k=3$. One then gets that
$$\Gamma(5/3)=\frac{2\pi\cdot 3^{-5/2}\cdot 2!}{1!\cdot \Gamma(4/3)}=\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}\cdot \Gamma(1/3)}\approx 0.90274529295.$$
This may already be satisfactory, but if you want an expression which is more intuitive to understand, note that you can express $\Gamma(1/3)$ in terms of the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) of $2$ and $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#General_rational_argument)):
$$\Gamma(1/3)=\frac{2^{7/9}\cdot \pi^{2/3}}{3^{1/12}\cdot \operatorname{AGM}\left(2,\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)^{1/3}}.$$
As such, we obtain the result:
$$\Gamma(5/3)=\frac{2^{11/9}\pi^{1/3}}{3^{17/12}}\operatorname{AGM}\left(2,\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)^{1/3}.$$
This expression is particularly nice because you could easily estimate the value of $\Gamma(5/3)$ if you don't have access to the $\Gamma$-function on a calculator. The AGM of two positive real numbers always satisfies $G\leq \operatorname{AGM}\leq A$, where $G$ is the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) and $A$ is the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean). In this case $G\approx 1.96563051084284$ and $A\approx 1.96592582628907$, which gives you a quite good estimate on the AGM.

Comment: Just realised that there is a slightly more elementary approach: Note that by using [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula#Known_formulae) with $z=2/3$:
$$\Gamma(5/3)=\frac{2}{3}\Gamma(2/3)=\frac{2}{3}\frac{\pi}{\sin(2\pi/3)\Gamma(1/3)}=\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}\cdot \Gamma(1/3)}.$$